# Trying to find if a process is alive in Python

Tags: python, psutil

I'm using [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) in order to know when a process is running.

So far I have this code:

```
PROCESS_NAME = 'python.exe'
for p in psutil.process_iter():
  if p.name == PROCESS_NAME:
    print("It's alive!")
    break
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.

I've looked around on google and here but every post suggests that the code above would be correct.

Unless I'm clearly misunderstanding how process_iter() works....

Comment: *"It doesn't seem to work"* how exactly?

Comment: It doesn't print or brake. And since it won't do either of those, that if is clearly False. But as I said, everywhere I've look says that this code should work fine.

Comment: Then it probably is working fine, and there is no process for which `p.name == "PROCESS_NAME"`. Add `else: print p.name` to your `if:`. Sort through the output and see if one of the processes you care about is there. See what its name actually is.

Comment: Adding an else: print (p.name) prints all the running processes. In my example I'm looking for pyhton.exe which is clearly running.

Comment: Yes, that is what it does. Does "python.exe" appear in the list of running processes?

Comment: Yes, yes it does...hence the confusion.

Comment: The confusion over what you were searching for (i.e. were you searching for a process named, literally, PROCESS_NAME; or were you searching for a process, and you let PROCESS_NAME stand for it in your code sample?) is a reason why you ought to provide a short, complete program copy-pasted directly from your text editor. If we had had a complete program, the error would have been immediately obvious. See http://SSCCE.org or http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Answer (score 1):

## Bad Python Syntax:

This line is wrong:

```
if p.name == "PROCESS_NAME":    # BAD
```

It looks for a process whose name is, literally, «PROCESS_NAME». Instead, you want to look for a process whose name is the same as the name referred to by the variable PROCESS_NAME, like so:

```
if p.name == PROCESS_NAME:      # GOOD
```

The right-hand-side of the first line is a string literal. The right-hand-side of the second is the name of a variable.

Of course, if you are always going to look for the same name, you can put **that** name in a string literal:

```
if p.name == "python.exe":     # ALSO GOOD
```

---

## New PSUTIL API:

Between version 1.2.1 and version 2 of `psutil`, they changed the api. In version 1, `p.name` is the name of the process. In version 2, `p.name` is a function which returns a string which is the name of the process.

So, try this:

```
if p.name() == PROCESS_NAME:
```

Comment: You have no idea how much I wish that worked. Here's literally a screenshot of the code: http://i.imgur.com/wFxn26e.jpg

Comment: That's a screenshot of the output. Where is the code?

Comment: You must be running a different version of `psutil` than I am. On my psutil, `p.name` is a string. On yours, it is a function. Can you `print psutil.version_info`?

Comment: print psutil.version_info == (2, 1, 1). I'm running Python 3.3.

Comment: All of my previous comments were based on (1,2,1). It seems they [changed the API](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil#process-management).

Comment: Well that solved it. Sort of. I'm getting a Access is denied error now, but that is beyond the scope of this question.